# の意味は何 versus はどういう意味

Tags: word-choice, spoken-language

What is the difference between の意味は何 and はどういう意味? When asking for the definition of a word, I've been told to use the latter, but I don't know why the former is incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the latter if you want to speak and write "natural" Japanese.  「～～はどういう意味ですか。」 is how native speakers ask for a word's definition.

「～～の意味はなんですか。」, while grammatical, sounds SO "directly translated" from "What is the meaning of ~~?".  It is not very natural, if not incorrect.

Comment: Why do native speakers ask this way? Why not ask literally for the meaning, versus "How to say the meaning", or whatever どういう意味 would translate to.

Comment: The どういう is like "what kind of~", rather than "How to say", no?

Comment: I recently heard a native Japanese teacher say "でも、意味は何?" in a class for children. Can some other native speakers confirm that this is really unnatural? I see the poster here seems to have his account suspended so cannot get confirmation from him.