# どういう in Place of Other Question Words

Tags: set-phrases

Related: [の意味は何 versus はどういう意味](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13802/%E3%81%AE%E6%84%8F%E5%91%B3%E3%81%AF%E4%BD%95%E3%80%80versus%E3%80%80%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E6%84%8F%E5%91%B3)

I was wondering why どういう is used in situations like asking for meanings of words, or in something like どういう状況, for "What's going on here?" Does anyone have a good reason why saying "How would you say" is favored over just asking a direct question like "What is the situation" or "What is the meaning?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

どういうXX here is like English "what kind of XX".  It's slightly vaguer with more room for expansion, and could come across as slightly more humble or non-confrontational on the part of the speaker.  In terms of rhythm and idiom, どういう状況ですか starts with どういう, immediately indicating that this is a question, rather than 状況は何ですか, where we're halfway through the utterance before there's any hint that it's a question.  By starting with a clear question phrase, the listener is primed to think of an answer.  This doesn't map very well to English, in that the word orders and emphases are quite different from *What kind of situation* (or perhaps the more literal translation of *how would you say [about] the situation*) vs. *What is the situation*, where the English in all these cases starts with a question word.